# VS Code function to go to next space

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I am trying to write a function that will go to the next space from the cursor. This is what I have so far, but I couldn't work out how to search from current cursor position:

```
// go to next space
function goToNextSpace(args) {
   const vscode = args.require('vscode');
   const regEx = /\s/;
   const ACTIVE_EDITOR = vscode.window.activeTextEditor;
   const text = ACTIVE_EDITOR.document.getText();
   const match = regEx.exec(text);
   const nextPos = ACTIVE_EDITOR.document.positionAt(match.index);

   return ACTIVE_EDITOR.selection = new vscode.Selection(
      nextPos, nextPos
   );
}
```

I have been looking at https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api but I simply couldn't find where it references how to use a regex.

### V2 after feedback from Matt

Thanks to @MattBierner, I now have the below code. I added 1 to the index to ensure that each time I call it, it goes to the next space (rather than just staying on the space last found). Now I am missing a way to go the next space on the next line if at the end of a line.

```
// go to next space
function goToNextSpace(args) {
   const vscode = args.require('vscode');
   const ACTIVE_EDITOR = vscode.window.activeTextEditor;
   const text = ACTIVE_EDITOR.document.getText();

   const regEx = /\s/g;
   regEx.lastIndex = ACTIVE_EDITOR.document.offsetAt(ACTIVE_EDITOR.selection.active) + 1;
   const match = regEx.exec(text);

   const nextPos = ACTIVE_EDITOR.document.positionAt(match.index);

   return ACTIVE_EDITOR.selection = new vscode.Selection(
      nextPos, nextPos
   );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the [`lastIndex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/lastIndex) property on your regular expression to the current cursor position (`ACTIVE_EDITOR.selection.active`):

```
 // You also need to enable global matching mode on your regular expression
 const regEx = /\s/g;

 regEx.lastIndex = ACTIVE_EDITOR.document.offsetAt(ACTIVE_EDITOR.selection.active)
```

This should ensure that you only find matches after the cursor position

Comment: OK, getting much closer. I incremented index by 1 which helped. Now what I am missing is how to find next space on the next line.. Does that need a specific check? I tried using `/\s|\n\s/g` but that didn't work.

Comment: Thanks for the hint about docs too - should have realised most of this is straight Javascript.

Comment: `\s` will also match newlines. If you want only to match space and tab for example, use a regular expression such as as `[ \t]`

Comment: Yeah, but the function as is doesn't move the cursor to the next line if at the end of a line.. am trying to work out that part now.

Answer (score 0):

Got this to work as a command for `vscode-powertools`.

1. Install [vscode-powertools](https://github.com/egodigital/vscode-powertools)
2. Define powertools commands in settings: `%APPDATA%\Code\User\settings.json`

   ```json
   "ego.power-tools": {
       "commands": {
           "goToNextWhiteSpaceInDocument": {
               // Cannot use environment variables.. yet. https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/2809
               // "script": "${env:APP_DATA}/goToNextWhiteSpaceInDocument.js",
               "script": "[absolute path to APPDATA with forward slashes]/Code/User/goToNextWhiteSpaceInDocument.js",
           },
           "goToPreviousWhiteSpaceInDocument": {
               // Cannot use environment variables.. yet. https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/2809
               // "script": "${env:APP_DATA}/goToPreviousWhiteSpaceInDocument.js",
               "script": "[absolute path to APPDATA with forward slashes]/Code/User/goToPreviousWhiteSpaceInDocument.js",
           }
       }
   }
   ```
3. Copy command files.

   1. Copy [command to go to previous white space](https://github.com/robertmarkbram/VS-Code-Customisations/blob/main/commands/goToPreviousWhiteSpaceInDocument.js) to `%APPDATA%\Code\User\goToPreviousWhiteSpaceInDocument.js`.
   2. Copy [command to go to next white space](https://github.com/robertmarkbram/VS-Code-Customisations/blob/main/commands/goToNextWhiteSpaceInDocument.js) to `%APPDATA%\Code\User\goToNextWhiteSpaceInDocument.js`.
4. Define keyboard shortcuts in `%APPDATA%\Code\User\keybindings.json`

   ```json
   {
       "key": "shift+alt+]",
       "command": "goToNextWhiteSpaceInDocument"
   },
   {
       "key": "shift+alt+[",
       "command": "goToPreviousWhiteSpaceInDocument"
   }
   ```

Code from `goToNextWhiteSpaceInDocument.js` is below.

```js
exports.execute = async (args) => {
    // args => https://egodigital.github.io/vscode-powertools/api/interfaces/_contracts_.workspacecommandscriptarguments.html

    // https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api
    const vscode = args.require('vscode');

    // Current editor.
    const activeEditor = vscode.window.activeTextEditor;
    // Position of cursor - starting point of current selection.
    const currentPosition = activeEditor.selection.start;
    // Current document.
    const currentDocument = activeEditor.document;
    // Current line.
    const currentLineLength = currentDocument.lineAt(currentPosition.line).text.length;
    // Current offset within editor (from start of current selection, 
    // which will be where the cursor is).
    const currentOffset = currentDocument.offsetAt(currentPosition);

    /*
        Return true if current position is at end of the current line.
    */
    function atEndOfCurrentLine() {
        return currentPosition.character === currentLineLength;
    }

    /*
        Return true if current position is at end of file.
    */
    function atEndOfFile() {
        return atEndOfCurrentLine() && onLastLine();
    }

    /*
        Change position to end of current line.
    */
    function goToEndOfCurrentLine() {
        // Go to end of line.
        const nextPosition = currentDocument.lineAt(currentPosition.line).range.end;
        activeEditor.selection = new vscode.Selection(nextPosition /* start */, nextPosition /* end */);
    }

    /*
        Change position to start of next line.
    */
    function goToStartOfNextLine() {
        // Go to start of next line.
        const nextPosition = currentDocument.lineAt(currentPosition.line + 1).range.start;
        activeEditor.selection = new vscode.Selection(nextPosition /* start */, nextPosition /* end */);
    }

    /*
        Jump next word: jump to end of next set of white space after current set of non-white space.
    */
    function jumpNextWord() {
        // From current position to end of line.
        const textToEndOfLine = currentDocument.getText(
            new vscode.Range(
                currentPosition.line   /* start line */, currentPosition.character  /* start column */,
                currentPosition.line   /* end line   */, currentLineLength          /* end column   */,
            )
        );

        // Result of looking for first white space in rest of line.
        const regexResult = /\s+/.exec(textToEndOfLine);

        // No result - near end of line (but not at end - we already tested for that).
        if (!regexResult) {
            // Go to end of line.
            goToEndOfCurrentLine();
            // Do nothing more.
            return;
        } else {
            // Go forward to next space. Work out next position we want to be at.
            const nextPosition = activeEditor.document.positionAt(currentOffset + regexResult.index + regexResult[0].length);
            activeEditor.selection = new vscode.Selection(nextPosition /* start */, nextPosition /* end */);
            return;
        }
    }

    /*
        Return true if current position is on the last line of the file.
    */
    function onLastLine() {
        return currentPosition.line === currentDocument.lineCount - 1;
    }

    if(atEndOfFile()) {
        // Do nothing.
        vscode.window.showInformationMessage('At EOF.');
        return;
    } else if (atEndOfCurrentLine()) {
        goToStartOfNextLine();
    } else {
        jumpNextWord();
    }

};
```