# VScode shortcut to select up to next space?

Tags: visual-studio-code, keyboard-shortcuts

You can select entire words with the shortcut `Ctrl + Shift + [Right/Left arrow]` but is there a shortcut to select everything up to next space? Say I want to select the text `foo/bar` the previous shortcut will stop at the `/` slash symbol, but I want to select up to the end of the expression, which in this case, will end at the next space.

I tried the vscode-powertools solution from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56998588/vs-code-function-to-go-to-next-space) but couldn't make it work.

Edit: I'm working on Windows 10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use the extension I wrote: [Select By](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rioj7.select-by)

Add this keybinding:

```json
  {
    "key": "ctrl+shift+alt+right",
    "when": "editorTextFocus",
    "command": "selectby.regex",
    "args": {
      "forward": " ",
      "forwardInclude": false
    }
  }
```

Comment: Do you know how to make it work backwards? That is, selecting from right to left up to next space

Comment: @Darvid Have you read the extension doc page: use `backward` and `backwardInclude`

Answer (score 0):

If <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> doesn't select everything you want (it depends on the separator between words),

then hit your <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>right/leftArrow</kbd>.

---

Or you could try this extension I wrote, [Jump and Select](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ArturoDent.jump-and-select).

Using the default keybinding <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> the command will select everything from the cursor to whatever character you type next - in your case a <kbd>Space</kbd>.

Answer (score -1):

Are you working with mac? Let's use `CMD + pattern` rather than `Ctrl + pattern`

Comment: No, I have Windows 10